# Where does attr_accessor come from

Tags: ruby

Where does `attr_accessor` come from? In the [documentaion](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html) it looks like `attr_accessor` is part of `Module`, but if I never see `Module` in an ancestors array:

```
class Foo
end

Foo.ancestors #=> [Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is indeed coming from `Module`. `Module` is not an ancestor of `Foo`. It is, however, an ancestor of `Class` and `Foo` is a class and thus an instance of `Class`.